# show can set disabled pop error: mysql select one: sql: no rows in result set

Tags: buffalo

```
err = db.Find(model)
err == "mysql select one: sql: no rows in result set"
```

I don't think this is a mistake. How do I turn it off in buffalo/pop?

and

```
errors.Is(err, sql.ErrNoRows)   === false
```

can't unwrap the error

```
    fmt.Println(111)
    for {
        fmt.Println("err:", err,err.Error(),reflect.TypeOf(err))
        err = errors.Unwrap(err)
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(222)


err: mysql select one: sql: no rows in result set mysql select one: sql: no rows in result set *errors.withStack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

buffalo/pop still uses the pkg/errors package (https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors) to wrap its errors. While it's still the case, you can use `errors.Cause` method from this package, and compare it to the `sql.ErrNoRows` error.

```golang
if errors.Cause(err) == sql.ErrNoRows {
// Do what you need here.
}
```